# Content not sitting in front of element behind content HTML

Tags: html, css

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hutber/uAczq/ Is the easiest way to explain it.

```
/html
<div title="1%">
    1% 
    <div class="background rating_90"></div>
</div>
//css
.rating {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.rating .background.rating_90 {
    width: 90%;
}
.rating .background {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    background-color: #75890C;
    border-right: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
}
```

Currently, the text inside the will not be visible, instead `.background` sits in front of the text.

I don't want to add another element inside of the parent `div`

Comment: Problem is with your positioning background image div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you do not need the `content` property as this is not a pseudo element.

However, you need to set the z-index of the bg div

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/uAczq/1/)

**CSS (extract)**

```
.rating .background {
   z-index:-1; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: Madness lol, I had tried z-index and indeed it works in the fiddle, but this doesn't work on my live version. I will need to play and see what is blocking this :)

Comment: Boom... Broken it :p http://fiddle.jshell.net/hutber/uAczq/3/ I will myself try and fix this now.

Comment: Dam it, its working in fiddle but not my site, even with the full css file!

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index: -1`.

z-index can only be used on explicitly positioned elements. That means anything with `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` can be positioned on the Z pane, or for a better understanding, the "depth" level within a page.

**Do:**

```
.rating .background {
   z-index: -1;
   /* The rest of your CSS */
}
```

You can also remove `content: '';` as it has no effect on non-pseudo selectors.

**[See Fiddle here.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/uAczq/2/)**